# Why am I not getting appropriate values for the outline I am creating - mask with pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I want to create an outline for a certain object - get a list of values (Tuple) corresponding to the outline according to the position of the object.

I get a list but it doesn't match the position of the object and I have to do another calculation to get the values contained on the list.

```py
self.pos = (random.randint(10, WIDTH - 50), random.randint(10, HEIGHT - 50))
self.mask = pygame.mask.from_surface(self.img).outline()
```

this is the list I get: (It does not match the location of the object)

```
[(4, 2), (5, 2), (6, 2), (7, 2), (8, 2), (9, 2), (10, 2), (11, 2), (12, 2), (13, 2), (14, 2), (15, 2), (16, 2), (17, 2), (17, 3), (18, 4), (19, 5), (19, 6), (19, 7), (19, 8), (19, 9), (19, 10), (19, 11), (19, 12), (19, 13), (19, 14), (19, 15), (19, 16), (19, 17), (19, 18), (19, 19), (18, 19), (17, 20), (16, 20), (15, 20), (14, 20), (13, 20), (12, 20), (11, 20), (10, 20), (9, 20), (8, 20), (7, 20), (6, 20), (5, 20), (4, 20), (3, 19), (2, 19), (2, 18), (2, 17), (2, 16), (2, 15), (2, 14), (2, 13), (2, 12), (2, 11), (2, 10), (2, 9), (2, 8), (2, 7), (2, 6), (2, 5), (3, 4), (4, 3), (4, 2)]
```

and this is the code I use to fix it but I would love to get rid of it:

```py
self.t = []
for i in range(len(self.mask)):
    self.t.append((self.pos[0] + self.mask[i][0], self.pos[1] + self.mask[i][1]))
```

Comment: You can't get around of the `for loop` when using masks but you could use list comprehension to make it more efficient.
`self.t = [(self.pos[0] + x, self.pos[1] + y) for x, y self.mask]`

Comment: @Jerry That's not the problem, please read the post again

Comment: See [`pygame.mask.Mask.outline`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/mask.html#pygame.mask.Mask.outline): *"Returns a list of points of the outline of **the first connected component encountered** in the mask."*. How many connected component has your image/mask?

Comment: @Rabbid76 only one component it's return a list but not in the correct place

Comment: There is absolutely nothing wrong with your code. The problem is not reproducible. Please read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

When you create an outline with [`outline()'](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/mask.html#pygame.mask.Mask.outline), you have to keep 2 things in mind:

1. Move the outline points created from the mask from the mask to the position on the screen

   ```py
   mask = pygame.mask.from_surface(surface)
   outline = mask.outline()
   rect = surface.get_rect(center = (cx, cy)
   window_points = [(p[0] + rect.x, p[1] + rect.y) for p in outline]
   ```
2. Depending on the image, the bits in the mask may not be completely continuous. To work around this, you can specify the number of bits to skip when creating the continuous contour with an optional parameter:

   ```py
   outline = mask.outline(3)
   ```

---

Minimal example

[image]

```py
import pygame

pygame.init()
window = pygame.display.set_mode((400, 400))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

surface = pygame.image.load('Apple1-256.png')
mask = pygame.mask.from_surface(surface)
outline = mask.outline(3)

run = True
while run:
    clock.tick(100)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False 

    window_center = window.get_rect().center
    rect = surface.get_rect(center = window_center)
    window_points = [(p[0] + rect.x, p[1] + rect.y) for p in outline]

    window.fill(0)
    window.blit(surface, rect)
    pygame.draw.lines(window, "white", True, window_points, 5)
    pygame.display.flip()

pygame.quit()
exit()
```